# No idea why my border-bottom not working can someone please solve it

Tags: html, css

I created a nav bar but my border-bottom not working , it is working as a border-top instead. I am trying to create a nav bar like twitter for learning. It will be a great help if someone helps me to solve it

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.header{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-bottom:  1px solid #dae0e4;
}
.container{
 width: 90%;
 margin: 10px auto;
}
.main-nav{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.second-nav{
 float: right;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 120%;
}
li a {
 color: #6f7d87;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.body{
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Twitter</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="page">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="main-nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Notification</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Messages</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="second-nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Search Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Tweet</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="body">
   <p>Something</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the border to show the lining downside but it is showing it upside, I couldn't find the solution anywhere on the web and also I was unable to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The border did appear, but visually on top of the header.

This is because the child elements of `.header` are floated and hence the height of `.header` becomes zero. To avoid this, add a clearfix to `.header`. Here I've used `overflow:auto` to fix it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-nav {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.second-nav {
  float: right;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 120%;
}

li a {
  color: #6f7d87;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.body {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Notification</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="second-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Search Bar</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Tweet</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but why there is overflow:hidden in ul ? @Akshay

Comment: @user11437679 There is no `overflow:hidden`, you just have to add `overflow:auto` to fix the height. You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix to see other methods to fix it.